# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/oss/driver/api/mapper/entity/naming/GetterStyle

Tags: spring-boot, lombok, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-4.0

I am building Cassandra datastax 4.14 with Spring Boot and gradle 7.6

Gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "2.3.5.RELEASE"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version "1.0.9.RELEASE"
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "6.6.3"
}


dependencies {
   ...

    implementation 'io.github.lognet:grpc-spring-boot-starter:4.5.4'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'

    // Cassandra
    annotationProcessor group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: lombokVersion
    annotationProcessor group: 'com.datastax.oss', name: 'java-driver-mapper-processor', version: cassandraSdkVersion

    implementation "com.datastax.oss:java-driver-mapper-runtime:4.14.0"
    implementation "com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.14.0"
    implementation "com.datastax.oss:java-driver-query-builder:4.14.0"
    compileOnly group: 'org.projectlombok', name: 'lombok', version: lombokVersion
    // Force native protocol.
    implementation "com.datastax.oss:native-protocol:1.5.1"

    ...
}
```

Simple Example of my code

```
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Mapper;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.DaoFactory;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.DaoKeyspace;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.DaoTable;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Dao;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.CqlSession;

@Mapper
public interface CassandraMapper {

    static CassandraMapper build(CqlSession session) {
        return new CassandraMapper(session).build();
    }

    @DaoFactory
    ExampleDao exampleDao(@DaoKeyspace String keyspace, @DaoTable String table);
}
```

Entity

```
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.Entity;
import com.datastax.oss.driver.api.mapper.annotations.PartitionKey;

@Data
@Builder
@Entity
public class EntityObject {
    @PartitionKey private long id;
    private Long version;
}
```

When I try to run gradle compileJava, I get the error:
`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/oss/driver/api/mapper/entity/naming/GetterStyle`

I've tried configuring annotationProcessor, I've read the docs at https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.14/manual/mapper/config/lombok/ and
https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/object-mapper-jvm/tree/master/lombok, but I can't seem to find any issues.

Comment: if you run this command "./gradlew dependencies", do you see "java-driver-mapper-runtime-4.14.0.jar" as part of output of above command?

Comment: Yes, I see it as part of the command. It is 4.14.0 everywhere except for one place, annotationProcessor, where it looks like it might be downgraded.


annotationProcessor
+--- com.datastax.oss:java-driver-mapper-processor:4.14.0
|    +--- com.datastax.oss:java-driver-mapper-runtime:4.14.0 -> 4.6.1
|    |    +--- com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.6.1
|    |    |    +--- com.datastax.oss:native-protocol:1.4.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like spring dependency management was downgrading my mapper library.

I added `annotationProcessor "com.datastax.oss:java-driver-mapper-runtime:4.14.0"` to my gradle file to force the correct version, and it builds now.